# Adding line breaks into procs with nested each iterators ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, each

Hey guys I'm learning Ruby and trying to connect it to PostgreSQL database in my computer. I have the connection and two tables created one with two tuples. I want to display the values of each tuple in its own line but add a line break '\n' between tuples.

I've been trying to apply my knowledge of Procs and figure out a way of making the queries reusable and thought Procs was a good idea although it would like a bit messy to some of you. You are free and welcome to criticize my code

```
res = conn.exec("select *  from one.employees") #The table with the tuples as Hashes

iter=Proc.new do
  |tuple| tuple.map{|tupleVals| tupleVals}
end      #This goes over each tuple 


stripTuples2=Proc.new do |hash| #a is a Hash containing all the tuples. 
   hash.each do
     |tuple| tuple.each{|str| puts "#{str[0]}: #{str[1].strip}"}.to_s+"\n" 
   end 
end  #End of stripTuples2
```

That's the structure and I call it like this

```
stripTuples2.call(iter.call(res))
```

Although it prints all the values, each one in a new line it omits the "\n" I added in the code, it was the only place It let me do it without trowing an error. What can I do to fix this or to make my code better?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual value of `res` (use `puts res.inspect` or `p res`) and an example of the actual output you want. Also, why are you using procs instead of just defining methods?

Comment: Well I actually used functions and the code got so much better and readable. Yeah I don-t know why I thought of the hardest solution. Thanks a lot I got it to work.